# Access host class from IronPython script

Tags: c#, ironpython

How do I access a C# class from IronPython script? 
C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    One, Two
}

var engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("t", new MyClass());
var src = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(...);
src.Execute(scope);
```

IronPython script:

```
class_name = type(t).__name__     # MyClass
class_module = type(t).__module__ # __builtin__

# So this supposed to work ...
mc = MyClass() # ???
me = MyEnum.One # ???

# ... but it doesn't
```

**UPDATE**

I need to import classes defined in a hosting assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set `t` to an *instance* of `MyClass`, but you're trying to use it as if it were the class itself.

You'll need to either import `MyClass` from within your IronPython script, or inject some sort of factory method (since classes aren't first-class objects in C#, you can't pass in `MyClass` directly). Alternatively, you could pass in `typeof(MyClass)` and use `System.Activator.CreateInstance(theMyClassTypeObject)` to new up an instance.

Since you also need to access `MyEnum` (note you're using it in your script without any reference to where it might come from), I suggest just using imports:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('YourAssemblyName')

from YourAssemblyName.WhateverNamespace import MyClass, MyEnum

# Now these should work, since the objects have been properly imported
mc = MyClass()
me = MyEnum.One
```

You might have to play around with the script source type (I think `File` works best) and the script execution path to get the `clr.AddReference()` call to succeed.

Comment: I can import a class from an external assembly. But I need to use a class from the hosting assembly. The one that starts the python script. I've tried to play with import, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: @Max: The hosting assembly is not special in any way -- you'll need to import from it just as you would from any other assembly. You can put the full, absolute path to its DLL in the `AddReference()` call -- if that works, then you know it's just a path/current directory issue (which can be annoying, but at least you'll know if the code works or not)

Comment: Since the script was being hosted I was sure that I do not need to import the hosting assembly. And now that I've tried I see it's working. It is strange though that when I passed the class instance and queried class name and module it seemed like the class is already a part of a global namespace.